# file_get_contents not working for fetching data from facebook using batch requests

Tags: php, file-get-contents, facebook-batch-request

file_get_contents not working for fetching fata from facebook using batch requests.Am  using the code below:

```
  $url='https://graph.facebook.com/?batch=[{ "method": "POST", "relative_url":"method/fql.query?query=SELECT+first_name+from+user+where+uid=12345678"}]&  access_token=xxxxxxx&method=post';
 echo  $post = file_get_contents($url,true);
it produces 
    Warning: file_get_contents(graph.facebook.com/?batch=[{ "method": "POST", "relative_url": "method/fql.query?query=SELECT+first_name+from+user+where+uid=12345"}]&access_to‌ ​ken=xxxx&method=post): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /home/user/workspace/fslo/test.php on line 9
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? They would be very useful for diagnosing potential problems.

Comment: Please report the error message you get here. If the above is your exact code it will be a PHP syntax error, because there are no quotes around the URL string.

Comment: I got the warning Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/?batch=[{ "method": "POST", "relative_url": "method/fql.query?query=SELECT+first_name+from+user+where+uid=12345"}]&access_token=xxxx&method=post): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /home/user/workspace/fslo/test.php on line 9

Comment: am tried with cUrl instead of file_get_contents,but still it not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say the most likely answer to this is that you need to pass the URL values through `urlencode()` - particularly the JSON string.

Also, you should be `POST`ing the data.

Try this code:

*NB: I presume you are building the URL from several variables. If you edit the question with your actual code, I will provide a solution using that code*

```
<?php

  $baseURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';

  $requestFields = array (
    'batch' => '[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"method/fql.query?query=SELECT+first_name+from+user+where+uid=12345678"}]',
    'access_to‌ken' => 'whatever'
  );
  $requestBody = http_build_query($requestFields);

  $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: ".strlen($requestBody)."\r\n"
                . "Connection: close\r\n",
      'content' => $requestBody
    )
  );

  $context = stream_context_create($opts);

  $result = file_get_contents($baseURL, FALSE, $context);
```

A "more standard" way to do this these days is with cURL:

```
<?php

  $baseURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';

  $requestFields = array (
    'batch' => '[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"method/fql.query?query=SELECT+first_name+from+user+where+uid=12345678"}]',
    'access_to‌ken' => 'whatever'
  );
  $requestBody = http_build_query($requestFields);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($requestBody),
    'Connection: close'
  ));

  $post = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: $requestBody = http_build_query($requestBody);
or   $requestBody = http_build_query($requestFields);

Comment: `$requestBody = http_build_query($requestFields);` is the right one - answer fixed above.

Comment: still it not working friend...it produce an error:{"error":{"message":"Top level access token not specified for batch request","type":"GraphBatchException"}}

Comment: Did you edit the `'access_to‌ken' => 'whatever'` line with your access token?

Comment: s,and i have the needed permissions in my accesstoken.